# I can't insert a new edge loop

Tags: modeling

I can't select all the faces even if they are on the same plane. I don't understand. There are no double edges, vertices or faces. I want to insert a new edge loop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) but can't create one all around.

[image]

Comment: Upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can look for ourselves.

Comment: You are using a mirror modifier, so you can only select the original geometry, the mirrored one will modify automatically. Loop cuts stop for several reasons: unconnected geometry, n-gons or wrong edgeflow. It's hard to tell without looking at your file. Please [edit] your question and add more information or a link to your file.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I realized there was a double edge on one of a vertical edge. So there was a disconnection between the edges. I 'm surprised because I used the fonction to Remove Doubles. Surely my mistake.

Comment: @Grobby, it would be good for you to type that up as a well-written answer and accept it, so that someone else who has the same problem knows to look for double edges. (It's okay to answer your own question ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I realized there was a double edge on one of vertical edges. So there was a disconnection between the edges. I used <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* operator however it didn't solve the problem so I should have deleted those vertices manually.

Comment: Remove doubles does not work if the vertices don't overlap in terms of occupying the same 3D space. When edge loops don't work when they should, it has almost always to do with geometry errors. Normally the edge loop stops around the area where the problem is located.